# Hovering a div over another Div where the contents will remain

Tags: javascript, html, css

So, what I want to do is position 2 divs side by side. When I hover over the left div, I want it to expand its width to the full page, while covering the right div. When I hover over the right div, I want to expand the width -100% so it covers the left div. I got them to both sit side by side as well as for the left div to transition to the right 100% and the right div to expand to the left -100%. The main problem I am having is that it will show 100% of the div on either side that it expands to. Here is my code.

As of now I am only using CSS properties, but let me know if some javascript will work better.

```
  HTML code

  <div id="parent">
  <div id="wide">Wide (rest of width)</div>
  <div id="narrow">Narrow (200px)</div>
  </div>

CSS Code

#narrow {
    margin-top: 100px;
    padding-top: 20px;
  float: right;
  width: calc(100% - 50%);
    height: 400px;
  background: lightblue;
    transition: width 2s;
    z-index: -1000;
}

#narrow:hover {
    width: 100%;
}

#wide {
    margin-top: 100px;
    padding-top: 20px;
  float: left;
  width: calc(100% - 50%);
  background: lightgreen;
    height: 400px;
    transition: width 2s;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
}

#wide:hover {
    width: -100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here we go! `position: fixed` and `z-index`!

```css
#narrow {
    padding-top: 20px;
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
    height: 400px;
    background: lightblue;
    transition: width 2s;
    z-index: 0;
    position:fixed;
    right:0;
}

#narrow:hover {
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}

#wide {
    padding-top: 20px;
    width: 50%;
    background: lightgreen;
    height: 400px;
    transition: width 2s;
    position:fixed;
    left:0;
    z-index: 0;
}

#wide:hover {
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="wide">Wide (rest of width)</div>
  <div id="narrow">Narrow (200px)</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution: position both divs absolute, both with a 0 z-index. with one of the having a right: 0; Then, set the width and z-index on hover.

```
<div id="parent">
  <div id="wide">Wide (rest of width)</div>
  <div id="narrow">Narrow (200px)</div>
</div>



#narrow {
    margin-top: 100px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    Float: right;
    width: 50%;
    height: 400px;
    background: lightblue;
    transition: width 2s;
    Z-index: 0;
    Position: absolute; right: 0;
}

#narrow:hover {
    width: 100%;
    Z-index: 1;
 }

#wide {
    margin-top: 100px;
    padding-top: 20px;
   float: left;
   width: 50%;
   background: lightgreen;
   height: 400px;
   transition: width 2s;
   position: absolute;
   Z-index: 0;
}

#wide:hover {
    width: 100%;
    Z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: awesome, thank you so much. Is there an advantage to this approach vs the others? I also tried doing this with flexbox properties but it got really confusing.

Comment: It's a case by cases basis.  I only use position fixed for items that are fixed when I'm scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

I added some of the common elements to a panel class. Setting your parent as relative gives the child panels a common starting point. Setting the panels as absolute will allow you to position them on the left and right of the window. Adding a z-index of 2 to the panel that is being hovered over brings it over the non-hovered panel.

```
<div id="parent">
    <div class="panel" id="wide">Wide (rest of width)</div>
    <div class="panel" id="narrow">Narrow (200px)</div>  
</div>

#parent {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:400px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.panel {
    margin-top:100px;
    padding-top:20px;
    height:100%;
    width:50%;
    z-index:1;
}
#narrow {     
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    background: lightblue;
    transition: width 2s;  
}

#narrow:hover {
    width: 100%;
    z-index:2;
    transition: width 2s;   
}

#wide {     
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    background: lightgreen;  
    transition: width 2s;    
}

#wide:hover {
    width:100%;
    z-index:2;
    transition: width 2s;   
}
```